# Runtime Error: Found an in-place operation that changes one the variables needed by gradient computation

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, ode

I'm training vanilla RNN in PyTorch to learn the changes in the hidden dynamics.

There's no problem with forward pass and bk prop for the initial batch but when it comes to the part where I
use prev. hidden state as initial state it's somehow considered as in-place operation.

I don't really understand why this makes a problem and how to solve it.

I tried to follow the given hint by setting `retain_graph=True` in `backward()`but no progress.

****Code edited****

```
#define a class for the neural DE func
class ODE_RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, x, hidden_size):
        super().__init__()

        self.x= x
        #self.h_0= h_0
        self.rnn= nn.RNN(1, hidden_size, nonlinearity='tanh', batch_first=True)
        self.dense= nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)


    def forward(self,t,k):
        y0, h_0= k
        print(k)
        h_t, h_n= self.rnn(self.x, h_0)
        y= self.dense(h_t)        

        return y, h_t

    #main function
    
    ii = 0    
    #training loop -> using standard bk prop
               
    for itr in range(1, niters + 1): 
        
        for batch in range(nbatchs):

            #get data batches
            t, x0, y0, true_y= get_batch(batch) 

            #make instance of ODEFunc
            func = ODE_RNN(x0, hidden_size).to(device) 
    
            #declare optimizer
            optimizer = optim.Adam(func.parameters(), lr=1e-3)  

            print("batch <{0}>\n".format(batch)+
                  "-----------------------------------------------------------\n"+
                  "t: {0}, {1}\n".format(t,t.size())+
                  "x0: {0}, {1}\n".format(x0,x0.size())+
                  "y0: {0}, {1}\n".format(y0,y0.size())                
                )
            
            if batch == 0:

               #clear grads
               optimizer.zero_grad()

               #forward pass
               pred_y, pred_h = odeint(func, tuple([y0, h_0]), t) #note: pred_xx.size()= eval_pts x batch x seq x feature  4D
               
               #print prediction vs true value
               print(
                     "pred_y: {0}, {1}\n".format(pred_y,pred_y.size())+
                     "true_y: {0}, {1}\n".format(true_y,true_y.size())              
               )

            else:
               
               prev_pred_h= pred_h[-1]
               print(prev_pred_h, pred_h)
               
               #clear grads
               optimizer.zero_grad()

               #forward pass
               pred_y, pred_h = odeint(func, tuple([y0, prev_pred_h]), t)

               print(
                     "pred_y: {0}, {1}\n".format(pred_y,pred_y.size())+
                     "true_y: {0}, {1}\n".format(true_y,true_y.size())              
               )

            #evaluate the loss
            loss = nn.MSELoss()(pred_y, true_y)

            print("loss: {0}\n".format(loss)+
                  "-----------------------------------------------------------"
            )
            
            #with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True):
            
            #bkprop error
            loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
            
            #update parameters
            optimizer.step()
```

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:147: UserWarning: Error detected in MmBackward. No forward pass information available. Enable detect anomaly during forward pass for more information. (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/python_anomaly_mode.cpp:85.)
  allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-a34fbe7cdca8> in <module>()
     60 
     61         #bkprop error
---> 62              loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
     63 
     64         #update parameters

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    145     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    146         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
--> 147         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    148 
    149 

RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [5, 1]], which is output 0 of TBackward, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to you clearing the gradients with optim.zero_grad(). Something like the following should work. You can try detaching tensors to do something like TBPTT with tensor.detach() if memory becomes an issue.

```
    ...
    #main function

    #training loop -> using standard bk prop
    for itr in range(1, niters + 1): 
        
        for batch in range(nbatchs):

            #get data batches
            t, x0, y0, true_y= get_batch(batch)  
            
            if batch == 0:

               #make instance of ODEFunc
               func = ODE_RNN(x0, h_0, hidden_size).to(device) 
               #declare optimizer
               optimizer = optim.Adam(func.parameters(), lr=1e-3)  
               #clear grads
               #optimizer.zero_grad()
               #forward pass
               pred_y, pred_h = odeint(func, tuple([y0, h_0]), t) #note: pred_xx.size()= eval_pts x batch x seq x feature  4D
               #print prediction vs true value

            else:
               
               prev_pred_h= pred_h[-1]

               #clear grads
               #optimizer.zero_grad()
               #forward pass
               pred_y, pred_h = odeint(func, tuple([y0, prev_pred_h]), t)

            #evaluate the loss
            loss = nn.MSELoss()(pred_y, true_y)

            #bkprop error
            loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        
            #update parameters
            optimizer.step()
```

EDIT: Upon closer inspection, you also have the same code running if batch is not 0. This creates a new optimizer and a new `func` every time it is run.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to this but I need to pass ```h_0``` to ```func``` initially then ```prev_pred_h``` afterwards. How can I do this without re-defining func and optimizer ?